# How to center a div that has transform-origin of top and left?

Tags: html, css

I have a div (.content) that has a transform-origin: top left and I need to center it. The thing is, I can only modify CSS of its wrapper (.wrap), but not of the actual div. I've, of course, tried margin: 0 auto, but that's not working. And neither is position: absolute (with left and right set as 0), though if I can avoid using absolute, even better.

Is there any way I can center this div?

This is the outline of my HTML and CSS:

```css
/* The part of CSS that I can't modify */

.content {
  height: 350px;
  width: 350px;
  background-color: darkblue;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.7);
  -moz-transform: scale(0.7);
  -o-transform: scale(0.7);
  transform: scale(0.7);
  -webkit-transform-origin: top left;
  -moz-transform-origin: top left;
  transform-origin: top left;
}


/* The part of CSS that I can modify */

.wrap {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Flexbox is probably the right solution here.

Comment: you should probably ask the question differently ... you should say that you need to center **considering** the scale applied

Comment: It would still be centered...it would just **appear** not to be. anything else would require JS I suspect.

Comment: try this : https://jsfiddle.net/h5erkoxt/1/ you have to add some margin left to cancel the scale effect

Comment: @Paulie_D if the values are known with some calculation we can make it centred

Comment: Indeed, but I suspect I'm assuming a dynamic solution is required. If fixed values are in play then we can "undupe" >)

Comment: Yeah, I'm afraid it needs to be dynamic. Thanks for the link Paulie, I tried the flexbox option but yeah, since I have several of these .content divs with different fixed heights and widths, it doesn't center them all properly.

Comment: Then I'm afraid JS is your solution. If you edit the question to express that I'd be happy to re-open it. But you should be aware that a `transform` is **entirely** visual so layout is *not actually affected*.

Comment: and why you don't simply change the transform origin to center?

Comment: @TemaniAfif I can't touch the .content div css. That has to stay unchanged.

Comment: @TemaniAfif If they're all 185px width on smaller screens, how do I use margin-left: calc that you suggested?

Comment: as you can see in the calc the formula is (width * scale / 2)